# Sick and ROS slam

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm working with a p3dx using Aria and ROS. I did a teleop package and then I used the sonar device to avoid obstacles.

Finally I added a sick laser. With the data obtained with this laser I have to draw a map. Does any ROS package do that? Maybe openCV?

Thank you beforehand

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42082/sick-and-ros-slam/) by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the GMapping package to create a 2D gridmap using your SICK:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2012-08-22**:
Thanks a lot. I get the buffer reading with an Aria callback (readingCB). So I guess I have to create ros callback and publish this buffer to gmapping node.

The readings are ArPoseWithTime.

Thank you

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-22**:
One more remark: GMapping uses the Laserscan message and odometry information from TF. So make sure to not only publish your laser message, but also the TF-frames needed, i.e. one odometry-start-frame, a base_link frame and one for the position of your laserscanner.

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2012-08-22**:
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2012-08-25**:
I have a problem. I'm working with MoblieSim and I have tow nodes: teleop_node and movement_node. The first one is running in my laptop and the second one in the p3dx. I need the stage package in order to know the odometry. How can I know the odometry from mobilesim instead of Stage Robot Simulator?

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-26**:
Since I guess this relates to a different issue, I propose you open a new question for that. You will get answers faster and from more people then...

**Comment by [Julio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1458/julio/) on 2012-08-26**:
Done. Thank you

PS: http://answers.ros.org/question/42342/mobilesim-and-gmapping/